# retrieving regular expression match group values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Here is the script;:

```
var output = []
output = this.getField("SelectedSoftware").value.match(/\$(\d{1,4}\.\d\d)/g);
```

Example text from the field:

Automate, Audition ($500.00), Citrix Receiver, AutoCAD ($54.93), Clarity Studio ($748.23), Audacity ($300.00), Audition ($500.00), Business Objects Dashboard, Audition ($500.00),

The problem I have is getting just the cost numbers so they can be added together to display a total. `(?<=\$)` doesn't seem to work. so I grouped the rest of the expression in Parentheses. However, I'm not sure how to get those group values instead of the full matches.

Comment: [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) always returns an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegExp.exec(string)` should be really helpful. In fact, it's the only way to obtain capture groups from a string. The implementation is a bit tough though, since `.exec()` only returns a single result.

Sample code:

```
var regex = /\$(\d{1,4}\.\d\d)/g,
    text = this.getField("SelectedSoftware").value,
    prices = [],
    total = 0,
    num;

// Assignments always return the value that is assigned.
// .exec will return null if no matches are found.
while((val = regex.exec(text)) !== null){
  // Capture groups are referenced with 'val[x]', where x is the capture group number.
  num = parseFloat(val[1]);
  total += num;
  prices.push(num);
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7a1vfLfg/1/)

This works because `RegExp` objects have a property called `.lastIndex` which it bases the next `.exec()` search on.

You can [read more about `.exec()` on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Comment: Thanks @GrandonBroseph. Aside from using parseFloat that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have is getting just the cost numbers so they can be added together to display a total. [**String.prototype.match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
>   always returns an array as you want.

See this complete [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/64sjmbt0/)

```
var output = []
output = "Automate, Audition ($500.00), "
         +"Citrix Receiver, AutoCAD ($54.93), "+
         +"Clarity Studio ($748.23), Audacity "
         +"($300.00), Audition ($500.00), Business "
         +"Objects Dashboard, Audition ($500.00),"
        .match(/\$(\d{1,4}\.\d\d)/g);
```

Output:

```
["$500.00", "$54.93", "$748.23", "$300.00", "$500.00", "$500.00"]
```

Now you can simply add all number using This regex `/(\d{1,4}\.\d\d)/g`.

---

Getting sum of these values:

```
var total = 0;
for(var _=0; _<output.length; _++)
    total += parseFloat(output[_]);
```

See [**OUTPUT**](http://jsfiddle.net/64sjmbt0/2/) `2603.16`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It seems to be finished now ;)

Comment: Using `parseInt()` might not be a good idea, since some of the numbers aren't integers. To retain decimal numbers, it might be a better idea to use `parseFloat()`.

Comment: So that i have tweak some regex and not used `parseInt` and used `parseFloat`. Pardon for troubling @GrandonBroseph

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?:  )` to create non-capturing groups, but I don't think you need it in this case.

[MDN: Working with regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Working_with_regular_expressions)

> **exec**: A RegExp method that executes a search for a match in a string.
>   It returns an array of information. 
> **test**: A RegExp method that tests
>   for a match in a string. It returns true or false. 
> **match**: A String
>   method that executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an
>   array of information or null on a mismatch. 
> **search**: A String method
>   that tests for a match in a string. It returns the index of the match,
>   or -1 if the search fails. 
> **replace**: A String method that executes a
>   search for a match in a string, and replaces the matched substring
>   with a replacement substring. 
> **split**: A String method that uses a
>   regular expression or a fixed string to break a string into an array
>   of substrings.

What you need is RegExp.exec, which will return an array of information form which you can get the captured group.

It returns an array with the whole match in `[0]`, then each captured group in the following array slots. So what you want is:

```
var price = /\$(\d{1,4}\.\d\d)/.exec("$59.99")[1];
```